# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class while initiating repository bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am trying to load some database values at start time of spring boot application. I have autowired service, and in service i have autowired Dao. Below is the error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'validationExpressionService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'validationExpressionDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IValidationExpressionDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ril.nfg.dao.bean.ValidationExpression

I have added @EnitityScan @EnableJPARepository
FYI, Primary key in the case in String, hope that is ok.

Entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * The Class ValidationExpression.
 */
package com.ril.nfg.dao.bean;

@Entity
@Table(name = "VALIDATION_EXPRESSION")
public class ValidationExpression implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9096950800262493651L;

    private String validationId;
    private String expression;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdOn;
    private String description;
    private String responseCode;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "VALIDATION_ID", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getValidationId() {
        return validationId;
    }

    public void setValidationId(String validationId) {
        this.validationId = validationId;
    }

     @Column(name = "EXPRESSION", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }

    public void setExpression(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }
//remaining getters and setters
}
```

Repository

```
package com.ril.nfg.dao.repos;

import com.ril.nfg.dao.bean.ValidationExpression;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * The Interface IValidationExpressionDao.
 */
@Repository
public interface IValidationExpressionDao extends JpaRepository<ValidationExpression, String> {
}
```

Service

```
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ValidationExpressionService {

    @Autowired
    IValidationExpressionDao validationExpressionDao;

    public List<ValidationExpression> getAll() {
        return validationExpressionDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Class with @Autwired Service

```
public class CacheModuleParam implements ApplicationContextAware{

private static List<ValidationExpression> validationExpressionList = null;

@Autowired
    ValidationExpressionService validationExpressionService;

@Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException {
validationExpressionList = validationExpressionService.getAll();
}
}
```

Application Class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ril.nfg"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication//(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.ril.nfg.dao.repos",entityManagerFactoryRef="oracleEntityManagerFactory")
//@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.ril.nfg.dao.bean")
public class NFGApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NFGApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

All solutions on internet focuses on @EntityScan. Please help me understand what is wrong with this code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have all this configuration? Simply put our application in the package tree one level above all the other classes and you can go with a class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NFGApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NFGApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Packages:

```
com.ril.nfg <- here you put NFGApplication
```

And all other classes in subpackages of com.ril.nfg

And then everything will work!

Comment: I moved NFGApplication class to com.ril.nfg and removed all the config. Error still persist. But realised configs were not necessary. Thanks